# AddAllDifferent constraint of sums of variables in ortools

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

With [image: a_1,a_2,..,a_n] and [image: b_1,b_2,...,b_n] and so on all being lists of IntVars, I'd like to add an AllDifferent constraint so that the sums of all lists are different.

If I do this the straight forward way, I get a `TypeError: NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeIndex()`. How is this done?

Edit: I am using the cp-sat solver.

Comment: You could create an intermediate var for each list `model.Add(tmp == sum(list))` and apply alldifferent to them

Comment: Yes, that worked (after fixing two other bugs in my code). Thanks!